# GROUP BY in STRING_AGG

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a postgresql query to find words in a database grouped by priority. It works fine and looks like this:

```sql
select 
    min(w.text) as text,
    min(w.id) as w_id,
    count(distinct w.text),
    min(pwt.priority) as priority
from 
    word as w
join topic_word tw ON tw.word_id = w.id
join profile_word_topic pwt on pwt.topic_id = tw.topic_id and pwt."level" = tw."level" 
group by w.text 
order by min(pwt.priority), min(w.id)
```

The result looks like this and has the correct number of words (10):

```
text |w_id|count|priority|
-----+----+-----+--------+
FOUR |   4|    1|       1|
FIVE |   5|    1|       1|
SIX  |   6|    1|       1|
SEVEN|   7|    1|       1|
EIGHT|   8|    1|       1|
NINE |   9|    1|       1|
TEN  |  10|    1|       1|
ONE  |   1|    1|       2|
TWO  |   2|    1|       2|
THREE|   3|    1|       2|
```

Now I want to concatenate the words into one string like this:

```sql
select 
    string_agg(distinct w.text, ','),
    count(distinct w.text),
    min(pwt.priority) as priority
from 
    word as w
join topic_word tw ON tw.word_id = w.id
join profile_word_topic pwt on pwt.topic_id = tw.topic_id and pwt."level" = tw."level" 
group by pwt.priority 
order by min(pwt.priority), min(w.id)
```

But now some words are duplicated and the total amount of words is 12:

```
string_agg                        |count|priority|
----------------------------------+-----+--------+
EIGHT,FIVE,FOUR,NINE,SEVEN,SIX,TEN|    7|       1|
FIVE,FOUR,ONE,THREE,TWO           |    5|       2|
```

How do I get rid of the duplicate words? And how do I fix the ordering?

Bonus points if you can tell me how to achieve this in SQLAlchemy, but that is secondary, as I believe porting this should be straight forward.

Thanks for your input in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now got it to work with a sub query like this:

```sql
select 
    string_agg(text, ','),
    count(text),
    min(priority)
from (
    select 
        min(w.text) as text,
        min(w.id) as w_id,
        count(distinct w.text),
        min(pwt.priority) as priority
    from 
        word as w
    join topic_word tw ON tw.word_id = w.id
    join profile_word_topic pwt on pwt.topic_id = tw.topic_id and pwt."level" = tw."level" 
    group by w.text 
    order by min(pwt.priority), min(w.id)
) sub
group by priority
```

Now I have the correct result (correct number of words and ordering is correct):

```
string_agg                        |count|min|
----------------------------------+-----+---+
FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN|    7|  1|
ONE,TWO,THREE                     |    3|  2|
```

So in theory my question is answered.
But I am wondering if this is achievable without a sub query.